# Materialized view:- enq: JI - contention wait lock caused due to Materialized view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I am trying to create a Materialized view on a highly transnational table with fast refresh on commit. I created the view and I am seeing below waits as materialized view should refresh on each commit. Could someone help me how can I avoid hitting into this problem?

[image: JI - contention waits]

```
SELECT s.sowner,
       s.vname,
       s.flag2,
       s.flag3
  FROM snap$ s,
       (    SELECT DISTINCT sowner, vname
              FROM snap_reftime$
             WHERE instsite = 0
        START WITH masobj# IN (294435)
        CONNECT BY PRIOR sowner = mowner AND PRIOR vname = master) v
WHERE     s.sowner = v.sowner
       AND s.vname = v.vname
       AND BITAND (s.flag, 32768) != 0
    enter code here
```

Comment: How often are you seeing that wait?  It's important to count the waits and know the numbers before taking action.  There are always strange waits happening, but if that wait only represents 1% of the time, then fixing it wouldn't make the process or system run more than 1% faster.

Comment: @JonHeller Its more than 1%. My problem here is base table is getting locked because of these waits.